# C++ libraries that implement Go goroutines or Go channels?

Tags: c++, concurrency, go

I'm working with a medium-sized C++ code base which is currently entirely single-threaded. The time has come, however, to pursue concurrency and parallelism for performance gains. I'm very interested in the concurrency model of Google's Go programming language, with very lightweight goroutines and a system of communicating channels.

Sadly, for a variety of perfectly valid reasons, the project needs to stay in C++. So my question is: Is there a C++ library that approximates the Go paradigm for parallelism? Specifically, is there an approximation of goroutines or go channels available for C++? My fallback plan is just to use boost::thread.

The application in question is a long-running proprietary simulation for the financial forecasting domain. It's usually CPU bound, but also gets blocked on IO when new data become available. Many of the computations involved are not dependent on previous results and could be fairly easily made to run in parallel. Being able to run the application in a distributed context is a long-term goal, but not one that needs to be solved immediately.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190231/looking-for-a-c-or-c-library-providing-a-functionality-similar-to-google-gos-c

Comment: You really need to be more specific about your project. Various types of applications will benefit (or not) different threading models. Be that coroutines (which goroutines basically are) or threads; perhaps an event model is better suited, or one of the various actor libraries. **Describe your application**.

Comment: I added a paragraph describing the application.

Comment: C.f. also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2dzna9/c_green_threads_and_coroutines_library/), [this](https://alexandrugris.github.io/native/coding/2017/03/09/C++-Play-GreenThreads.html) and [this](https://github.com/duckie/boson).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your aim is primarily speeding up compute things, Intel's [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation/) (Threading Building Blocks) is (IMHO) a better option than rolling your own inferior version from `boost::thread`.

Comment: TBB looks like a good option, but I'd only pick it if I were convinced that there's no equivalent library that we could use for free.

Comment: TBB *is* free: there is a version that is distributed under Apache Public License on the linked site.

Comment: Tbb is great. Be aware that it is designed for compute tasks not for blocking tasks.

Answer (score 5):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121757/how-do-you-implement-coroutines-in-c) and in a general a google search for "C++ coroutines" should get you something close. The SO question suggests trying Boost::coroutine.

If you don't mind wrapping C you *might* be able to try [libtask](https://swtch.com/libtask/). Which was written by Russ Cox (one of the official Go dev team) before work on Go began. I've only used it in C though, so I don't know if it's applicable.

Go channels are implemented as locking queues by the way, so you might be able to incorporate a similar mechanism using regular threads.

Comment: Look like libtask has moved. Looks like a fork can be found in GitHub at https://github.com/jamwt/libtask

Comment: @RichardChambers It seems to have moved to https://swtch.com/libtask/ now, I've updated the post

Comment: [libgolang](https://lab.nexedi.com/kirr/pygolang/blob/master/golang/libgolang.h) provides Go-like channels and coroutines. Its C-level API was inspired by libtask. However it also provides safe C++-level API. Additionally libtask is [single-threaded](https://github.com/jamwt/libtask/blob/master/README#L13-L15) while libgolang comes with runtimes for both a) coroutines over one OS thread, and b) multiple OS threads that can interact with Go-style channels. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59088608/9456786 for details.

Answer (score 4):

[coost](https://github.com/idealvin/coost)

A go-style C++ coroutine library.

```
void fun() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}

go(fun);
go([]() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
});
```

It also provides:

- co::event
- co::mutex
- co::pool
- co::chan (similar to channel in golang)
- co::wait_group (similar to sync.WaitGroup in golang)

Answer (score 3):

Try [GBL library](http://www.gbresearch.com/gbl), it has everything: coroutines (fibers), threads, sync and async handlers -- and it's all modern C++.

Comment: Dead link. Now there is [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214125708/http://www.gbresearch.com/gbl/)

Comment: I can't find the source code for this. And it seems to me that the fibers don't conform to goroutines.

Answer (score 3):

[libgolang](https://lab.nexedi.com/kirr/pygolang/blob/master/golang/libgolang.h) provides `go` and channels including working `select`. Here is example usage:

```c
      chan<int> ch = makechan<int>(); // create new channel
      go(worker, ch, 1);              // spawn worker(chan<int>, int)
      ch.send(1)
      j = ch.recv()

      _ = select({
          _default,       // 0
          ch.sends(&i),   // 1
          ch.recvs(&j),   // 2
      });
      if (_ == 0)
          // default case selected
      if (_ == 1)
          // case 1 selected: i sent to ch
      if (_ == 2)
          // case 2 selected: j received from ch

      defer([]() {
          printf("leaving...\n");
      });

      if (<bug condition>)
          panic("bug");
```

`go` spawns either a thread or gevent-based coroutine depending on activated runtime.

Comment: Could you please put this on Github as a separate library?

Comment: @yesudeep, there is already [github mirror](https://github.com/navytux/pygolang) and libgolang could be already used from C++ part of another project - see e.g. [here](https://lab.nexedi.com/kirr/wendelin.core/blob/e2629822/wcfs/client/wcfs.h) ([2](https://lab.nexedi.com/kirr/wendelin.core/blob/e2629822/setup.py#L293-297)).

In the future I will try to add pkgconfig support, so that libgolang could be discovered and used without python dependency. However there is no plan to split libgolang into its own repository, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen so far, [cilk](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/) seems to be quite similar to go's style of parallelism. It looks like Intel has bought it and provides commercial support with [Intel Cilk Plus](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cilk-plus/).